# 'mem_fun' : is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005, std, visual-studio-2015

I've been experiencing this error for a while now, on every project that I have built with the CryEngine2 SDK in Visual Studio 2013 Professional.
Most of the time, I have just edited the function from this:

```
void CMultipleGrabHandler::Reset()
{
    std::for_each (m_handlers.begin(), m_handlers.end(), std::mem_fun (&CBaseGrabHandler::Reset));

    std::vector <CAnimatedGrabHandler*>::iterator it = m_handlers.begin();
    std::vector <CAnimatedGrabHandler*>::iterator end = m_handlers.end();
    for ( ; it != end; ++it)
        delete *it;

    m_handlers.erase (m_handlers.begin (), m_handlers.end ());
}
```

to this:

```
void CMultipleGrabHandler::Reset()
{
}
```

I know it's not a good approach to the problem, but it got rid of the `'mem_fun' : is not a member of 'std'` error.

I am now looking for a solution to overcome this problem, since I have just started working on a new project, where stability is key; it's *not good* if I remove the body of `CMultipleGrabHandler::Reset()`, since it could possibly induce crashes in certain situations.
I have browsed the internet for a solution to this problem, but I have not found anything (closest thing I found was an explanation of what `mem_fun` does).

I have tried taking `std::` off `mem_fun`, but I just get an `mem_fun is undefined` error, suggesting that this isn't exactly the right way to go about mending this error.

The project was originally created in Visual Studio 2005, and was migrated to Visual Studio 2013's format when I first opened the solution. 
Might this be the cause of the problem?
How can it be fixed?

***Edit:*** Added [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) as this also applies to the new VS version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `std::mem_fun` is defined in the header `<functional>`.

On some older compilers, you don't necessarily need to `#include` a standard library header in order to use functions and classes defined in that header, because it might already be included by some other standard library header that you `#include`. This is not exclusive to VS; it was also true for older gcc versions, like 4.0. Newer compilers are more standard-conforming and will require you to `#include` the actual headers that define standard library functions and classes.

Comment: The old vs new compiler thing isn't really true. The standard explicitly says that headers may include other headers.

Comment: @JosephMansfield It does say that, but I still think my interpretation is correct (but I'm open to being proven wrong). For example, `iostream` may include `string`, but that doesn't permit the implementation to actually make `std::string` available if you've included `iostream` but not `string` in your program.

Comment: No, your interpretation is incorrect.  When the specification says that "a C++ header may include other C++ headers" (N3797 §17.6.5.2[res.on.headers]/1), it is meant literally.  So `<iostream>` may literally include `<string>`, and including `<iostream>` may very well cause e.g. `std::string` to be declared.